# Binary Number Representation in 3d tikz node box

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, box, number

My effort is

```
\documentclass[margin=1in]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, backgrounds, positioning, fit, petri]


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
        box/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=0.5cm},
        value/.style={yshift=-1cm}]
        \node[box] (b7) {1};
        \node[box] (b6) [right=of b7] {1};
        \node[box] (b5) [right=of b6] {1};
        \node[box] (b4) [right=of b5] {1};
        \node[box] (b3) [right=of b4] {1};
        \node[box] (b2) [right=of b3] {1};
        \node[box] (b1) [right=of b2] {1};
        \node[box] (b0) [right=of b1] {1};
        
        \node[value] [below of=b0] {$2^0$};
        \node[value] [below of=b1] {$2^1$};
        \node[value] [below of=b2] {$2^2$};
        \node[value] [below of=b3] {$2^3$};
        \node[value] [below of=b4] {$2^4$};
        \node[value] [below of=b5] {$2^5$};
        \node[value] [below of=b6] {$2^6$};
        \node[value] [below of=b7] {$2^7$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I draw this binary number representation in tikz like 3d box node type. Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Questions posting an image and asking 'how do I do that?' are not reasonable question to post on this website. Please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far showing some effort on your part and pointing out a technical problem that you encountered while writing your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable picture for the binary number `1111111` but for a binary number like `101010111` I think that the picture should be:

[image]

The code below defines a macro `\BinaryNumber` that accepts a comma separated list of binary digits. Once this is defined, you can use

```
  \BinaryNumber{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
  \BinaryNumber{1,0,1,0,1,1,1}
  \BinaryNumber{1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1}
```

to produce:

[image]

Here is the code. I explain a little how it works below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/byte cube/.style args = {#1,#2}{
      code = {
         \draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
         \node at (0.5,0.5){#1};
         \draw[cube #1] (0,0)--(-60:2mm)--++(1,0)--++(0,1)--++(120:2mm)--(1,0)--cycle;
         \draw(1,0)--++(-60:2mm);
         \node at (0.5,-0.5){$2^{#2}$};
      }
    },
    cube 1/.style = {fill=gray!30}, % style for bytes that are "on"
    cube 0/.style = {fill=white},   % style for bytes that are "off"
}

\newcommand\BinaryNumber[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     % count the number of bytes and store as \C
     \foreach \i [count=\c] in {#1} { \xdef\C{\c} }
     \foreach \i [count=\c, evaluate=\c as \ex using {int(\C-\c)}] in {#1} {
       \pic at (\c, 1) {byte cube={\i,\ex}};
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}

}
\begin{document}

  \BinaryNumber{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}          \bigskip

  \BinaryNumber{1,0,1,0,1,1,1}              \bigskip

  \BinaryNumber{1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1}      \bigskip

\end{document}
```

The main idea is to use a `pic` to draw each byte (see section 18.2 of the [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZ) manual). The pic, called `byte cube` takes two arguments: `{0 or 1, exponent}`. The pic draws the "byte cube" with the fill colour below the  number being set to the corresponding style of `cube 0` or `cube 1`. Changing these styles will change the shading under the number. (So, by design, the choice of style depends on the binary digit.)

The definition of `\BinaryNumber` first loops through the bytes to determine the "length" of the binary number and then loops through them again to draw each "byte cube". Each successive byte cube draws over those parts of the previous cubes that we "do not want". Consequently, even though the shading on the right hand side is drawn for every cube it is only visible for the rightmost cube.

Answer (score 3):

A first easy solution can be the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=1in]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, backgrounds, positioning, fit, petri]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
        box/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=0.5cm},
        value/.style={yshift=-1cm}]
        \node[box] (b7) {1};
        \node[box] (b6) [right=of b7] {1};
        \node[box] (b5) [right=of b6] {1};
        \node[box] (b4) [right=of b5] {1};
        \node[box] (b3) [right=of b4] {1};
        \node[box] (b2) [right=of b3] {1};
        \node[box] (b1) [right=of b2] {1};
        \node[box] (b0) [right=of b1] {1};
\def\xasn{1mm}% x direction of the box
\def\yasn{-1.5mm}% y direction of the box
\fill[lightgray] (b0.north east) -- ([shift={(\xasn,\yasn)}]b0.north east) -- ([shift={(\xasn,\yasn)}]b0.south east) -- (b0.south east);
\draw (b0.north east) -- ([shift={(\xasn,\yasn)}]b0.north east) -- ([shift={(\xasn,\yasn)}]b0.south east);

\foreach \boxnr in {0,1,...,7} {
\draw[fill=lightgray] (b\boxnr.south west) -- +(\xasn,\yasn) -- ([shift={(\xasn,\yasn)}]b\boxnr.south east) -- (b\boxnr.south east);
}
        
        \node[value] [below of=b0] {$2^0$};
        \node[value] [below of=b1] {$2^1$};
        \node[value] [below of=b2] {$2^2$};
        \node[value] [below of=b3] {$2^3$};
        \node[value] [below of=b4] {$2^4$};
        \node[value] [below of=b5] {$2^5$};
        \node[value] [below of=b6] {$2^6$};
        \node[value] [below of=b7] {$2^7$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]